# Selecting values from one column based on a different columns value

Tags: sql, db2

Having trouble stating my problem succinctly here, so I'll just give an example.
Let's say I have a DB2 table about Students:

```
Name           Class          Grade
Billy J        Econ           A
Sarah S        Maths          B
Greg X         Computes       A-
Billy J        Maths          D
Greg X         Maths          C+
```

And I want to retrieve those students that are in both Econ and Maths, and display the information thusly:

```
Name       Maths Grade       Econ Grade
Billy J    D                 A
```

How in the world can I accomplish this?

Comment: What Database System?  SQL Server, MySQL, etc...

Comment: DB2, edited for elaboration.  Good question.

Comment: This problem can be solved without reference to product-specific features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution will solve the problem for the two classes you named:

```
SELECT Name, Math.Grade AS MathsGrade, Econ.Grade AS EconGrade
  FROM Students Math INNER JOIN Students Econ ON Math.Name = Econ.Name
  WHERE Math.Class = 'Maths' AND Econ.Class = 'Econ'
```

The only thing that this solution doesn't do is include the spaces in your derived column names.  You can do that by writing `Maths Grade` and `Econ Grade` in whatever characters DB2 uses for identifier quotes.

To be included students must have both a Maths and an Econ grade.

Comment: Perfect!  Cheers! Solved my immediate problem and I got better at writing queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from Students
where id in 
(SELECT id from Students where Class = 'Econ')
AND id in
(SELECT id from Students where Class = 'Math');
```

Comment: Returns multiple rows, not one, and will include rows for non-Maths, non-Econ classes.